# MySQL 5.7 generated DATE column with reference to TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sql-insert, mysql-5.7

I have a `created_at` column in my table and want to add a `created_at_day` column with type `DATE`.
The `created_at_day` column should initialize with the current date.

The way I tried to do that is with a generated column, as there is no `DEFAULT CURRENT DATE` or similar.
The problem is, I get an error when inserting a new record:
`Error executing INSERT statement. Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00' for column 'created_at_day' at row 1 - Connection: Localhost: 48ms`

I found two possible solutions that both have drawbacks.
One is to change the `TIMESTAMP` to `DATETIME`. For some reason a `DATETIME` column with `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` works, but I would prefer to not change every one of my `TIMESTAMP` columns to `DATETIME`.
Another thing that works is to disable `NO_ZERO_DATE` in SQL mode. For some reason when I disable that, the date column even gets initialized with the correct value and not `0000-00-00`. But this feels like a workaround rather than a solution, and may lead to future problems.

Is there another easy way to create a `DATE` column that is initialized with the current date?

Here is example code that produces the error:

```
create table test(
  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  created_at_day DATE AS (DATE(created_at))
);

insert into test values();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, you can just do:

```
create table test(
    created_at_day date as (current_date)
);
```

In MySQL 5.7, I don't think this can be done with just the table definition. You would need a trigger:

```
create table test(
    created_at_day date
);

delimiter //

create trigger trg_test_created_at_day
before insert on test 
for each row
begin
    if (new.created_at_day is null) then
        set new.created_at_day = current_date;
    end if;
end//

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DATE_FORMAT function on NOW():

```
CREATE TABLE test(stamp DATE default (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d')) NOT NULL);
```

Comment: This is not supported in MySQL 5.7 though.

Comment: @GMB What exactly is not supported? Thanks!

Comment: Using an expression as a default is not supported in MySQL 5.7: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0335a2da5609e2f7fce20b2d0a872fdf

Comment: Yeah I tried something like that, but NOW() is not supported as default

Comment: @stschmitt Yes, I am sorry. As GMB explained expressions are not supported in your mysql version.