# SQL: How to make a variable that auto generates years

Tags: mysql

Hello and welcome to my idiotic question.

I am starting working with sql and I want to make a table like this:

```
create table manager(

id int primary key not null,
working_comp int,
started_working year,
years_passed year default {getdate() - started_working} not null,
foreign key (working_comp) references company(company_AFM)

);
```

Explaining: I want the column years_passed to represent the years that the manager is working for the company, so I want it to be generated automatically from the current **date** minus the date that he started working for the company

I don't even know if it can be done

Could you please enlighten me??

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65252762/243925) says you should be able to use the current date in a generated column in MySQL 8. I'm not able to verify it though.

Comment: Yes, in this question @BrainlessPOMO is ussing it too through `getdate()`, but it's always calculated at the time of INSERT, not on SELECT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that is something you don't do in a SQL table. It is not the usual use case, at least not in a table. But you have a couple of really good alternatives:

**Option 1**

SQL has what it is called VIEWS. Which are like virtual tables. They are used to create "calculated" tables. With usual joins or operations that are used frequent in your business. I'd create a view that claculates in an extra column the years you want:

```sql
create view manager2 as 
Select id, working_comp, started_working,getdate() - started_working as years_passed
from manager;
```

You just insert in your normal table but when querying you do it in the view.

**Option 2**

You could do the calculation in the language you use to develop you application (the one that connecta to the database). So, whenever you query your data, you do the calculation.

Here you have 2 options too. Donthe calculation in the developimg language after the query, or directly do it in the select statement, like in the view.

My recomendation, for a simple calculation like that one, would be to do it in the select statement. You don't need a whole view for that.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a very good explanation!!

Comment: You are most welcome :D